# How Do I Write a SubSonic Select Statement that Sums Three Columns?

Tags: subsonic

I have to SUM 3 Columns and return the value in my result. What is the proper way to write this?

```
SubSonic.SqlQuery qs =new SubSonic.Select()
.From(Table.ViewAllratingsGlo.Schema.TableName);

SubSonic.Aggregate ag = SubSonic.Aggregate.Sum(("Column1+Column2+Column3), "Score");
qs.Aggregates.Add(ag);

string SqlResult = qs.BuildSqlStatement();
```

In the `SqlResult` I just see the Aggregate Query like

```
Select SUM("Column1+Column2+Column3) As 'Score'
```

But I need the other fields from my table too.

Answer (score 1):

In that kind of query, all the columns in your select statement need to be aggregate objects, just change the aggregate type to group by instead of sum.

```
SubSonic.SqlQuery qs = new Select(
    new SubSonic.Aggregate("column1+column2+column3", "Score", AggregateFunction.Sum), //the original
    new SubSonic.Aggregate(TableName.Column4, AggregateFunction.GroupBy), //another column
    new SubSonic.Aggregate(TableName.Column5, AggregateFunction.GroupBy) //another column
)
.From(Table.ViewAllratingsGlo.Schema.TableName);
```